# Math of Gaussian Mixture Models & EM Algorithm

Tags: clustering, gaussian, expectation-maximization, gmm

I'm having a hard time understanding the math behind GMMs.

A GMM is a weighted sum over K different Gaussian components with parameters $\mu_k, \sigma_k, \pi_k$

From my understanding, the general overview is:

1. Initialize random parameters for each k'th component
2. Use pdf $p(x | \mu_k, \sigma_k) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ to compute a responsibility value for each component
3. Use this responsibility value to update parameters $\mu_k, \sigma_k, \pi_k$

My questions are:

1. When and where is Bayes Rule used in this?
2. When and how exactly does the log likelihood function play into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question!

> 1. When and where is Bayes Rule used in this?

1. **Bayes Rule** is used in the **E-step** of the **Expectation-Maximization (EM)** algorithm for **GMMs**. In the **E-step**, the algorithm computes the probability that each data point belongs to each component of the **GMM**. This is done using Bayes Rule to compute the **posterior probability** of each component given the data point. Specifically, **Bayes Rule** is used to compute the conditional probability of the data point given each component, which is then multiplied by the **prior probability** of the component to obtain the **posterior probability**. This step is sometimes referred to as the **responsibility calculation** since it computes the responsibility of each component for each data point.

> 2. When and how exactly does the log likelihood function play into this?

2. The **log-likelihood** function is used to evaluate the **goodness of fit** of the **GMM** to the data. In the **M-step** of the **EM** algorithm, the parameters of the **GMM** are updated to maximize the **log-likelihood** function. Specifically, the mean, variance, and weight parameters of each component are updated to maximize the expected complete data **log-likelihood**, which is the sum of the expected log-likelihood of each data point under the current **GMM** parameters. The **EM** algorithm iterates between the **E-step** and the **M-step** until convergence is reached.

The math behind **Gaussian Mixture Models (GMMs)** can be a bit tricky to understand at first, but once you get the hang of it, it becomes quite intuitive.

**Bayes Rule** is actually used in the initial step of the **EM algorithm**, which is used to estimate the parameters of the **GMM**. The **EM algorithm** is an iterative method that maximizes the **likelihood function** of the observed data given the **GMM** parameters.

In the **E-step** of the **EM algorithm**, we compute the **posterior probability** of each data point belonging to each **Gaussian component** using the **Bayes Rule**.

**Bayes Rule** states that:

$$
P(A \mid B)=\frac{P(B \mid A) P(A)}{P(B)}
$$

Specifically, we use the following formula:

$$
p\left(z_k \mid x_n, \theta^{(t)}\right)=\frac{\pi_k^{(t)} \mathcal{N}\left(x_n \mid \mu_k^{(t)}, \sigma_k^{2(t)}\right)}{\sum_{j=1}^K \pi_j^{(t)} \mathcal{N}\left(x_n \mid \mu_j^{(t)}, \sigma_j^{2(t)}\right)}
$$

where

- $x_n$ is the $n^{th}$ data point,
- $z_k$ is a binary random variable indicating whether $x_n$ belongs to the $k^{th}$ Gaussian component,
- $\theta^{(t)}$ represents the current estimate of the GMM parameters, and
- $\mathcal{N}(x_n|\mu_k^{(t)},\sigma_k^{2(t)})$ is the probability density function of a Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu_k^{(t)}$ and variance $\sigma_k^{2(t)}$ evaluated at $x_n$.

This formula gives us the probability that each data point belongs to each **Gaussian component** given the current estimate of the **GMM** parameters. These probabilities are used to update the **GMM** parameters in the **M-step** of the algorithm.

The **log-likelihood** function comes into play in the **M-step** of the **EM algorithm**. In this step, we update the **GMM** parameters to maximize the **log-likelihood** of the observed data. Specifically, we update the mean, variance, and weight parameters of each **Gaussian component** using the following formulas:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mu_k^{(t+1)} & =\frac{\sum_{n=1}^N p\left(z_k \mid x_n, \theta^{(t)}\right) x_n}{\sum_{n=1}^N p\left(z_k \mid x_n, \theta^{(t)}\right)} \\
\sigma_k^{2(t+1)} & =\frac{\sum_{n=1}^N p\left(z_k \mid x_n, \theta^{(t)}\right)\left(x_n-\mu_k^{(t+1)}\right)^2}{\sum_{n=1}^N p\left(z_k \mid x_n, \theta^{(t)}\right)} \\
\pi_k^{(t+1)} & =\frac{\sum_{n=1}^N p\left(z_k \mid x_n, \theta^{(t)}\right)}{N}
\end{aligned}
$$

where $N$ is the number of data points.

After updating the parameters, we compute the **log-likelihood** of the observed data using the following formula:
$$
\ln p(X \mid \theta)=\sum_{n=1}^N \ln \sum_{k=1}^K \pi_k \mathcal{N}\left(x_n \mid \mu_k, \sigma_k^2\right)
$$

The goal of the **EM algorithm** is to iteratively update the **GMM** parameters to maximize this **log-likelihood**. When the change in the **log-likelihood** between iterations is below a certain threshold, we consider the algorithm to have converged and return the final estimate of the **GMM** parameters.

In simple words, the **log-likelihood** function comes into play during the **iterative optimization process**. The goal of **GMM** is to maximize the **log-likelihood** function with respect to the parameters $\mu_k, \sigma_k, \pi_k$. In other words, we want to find the parameters that make the observed data most likely. During each iteration, we compute the **log-likelihood** of the data given the current parameter values and then update the parameters to increase the likelihood of the data. This iterative process continues until **convergence** (i.e. when the change in **log-likelihood** between successive iterations falls below a certain threshold).

I hope this helps clarify the use of Bayes Rule and log likelihood in GMMs!

Comment: Amazing explanation. Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate it alot.

Comment: Glad that it helped :)